# Returning values from a function :(

Tags: python, function, parameters, boolean, boolean-logic

Please can someone explain what's going wrong here?
Unfortunately, I have been tasked to complete this using a function; otherwise, I would've used a built-in function like count()
Thanks!

```
scores = [3,7,6,9,4,3,5,2,6,8]
y = int(input("What score are you searching for in the scores array?  "))
a = len(scores)
z = False
def count1(c,b):
    for d in range(0,c):
        if scores[d] == y:
            print("yes")
            b = True
            return(b)
            
        else:
            print("no")                      
count1(a,z)
    
if z == True:
    print(y, "occurs in the array")
else:
    print(y, "does not occur in the array")
```

my code^

```
Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Users\18skeffingtonc\
What score are you searching for in the scores array?  3
yes
3 does not occur in the array
```

the output, after entering what should be a valid input^

Comment: Python is pass by value, so writing `b = True` inside the function achieves nothing, as it only modifies the variable inside the function

Comment: could you elaborate, what could I do to fix it?

Comment: Return a value in all code paths and then actually use it, instead of just ignoring it like you do now

Comment: @ceskeff11, when you pass `z` to your `count1` function, the function takes the value of `z` assigns it to a local variable `b`, and then does stuff with `b`. Nothing actually happens to the original variable `z` - its VALUE is passed into the function and then worked with. When the function call ends, `z` remains unchanged - so when you run your `if z==True` block, `z` always evaluates to `False`.

Comment: @vin is there any way I could return the value of b and assign it to the value of z?

Comment: @UnholySheep It is not a matter of pass-by-value. Python actually passes the reference. The issue is that `=` does not modify the data in the object on the left-hand side of the equation. It changes what the variable (in this case the local variable) refers to. Either way, of course, `b = True` does not do what OP expects.

Comment: Quite honestly your entire function could just be a `return y in c` or `return y in scores` - there is no attempt at counting, so the name of the function is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

The basic fix to your immediate problem is to modify the line `count1(a, z)` to read `z = count1(a, z)`.

That way, you give `z` to your `count1`, allow `count1` to modify `z`, and then overwrite the old value of `z` with the new value generated by your `count1`.

That said, you have a lot going on in your code that you don't really need. One concise way to do what you're attempting would be:

```
scores = [3,7,6,9,4,3,5,2,6,8]

def count1(scores):
    y = int(input("What score are you searching for in the scores array?  "))
    print (f'{y} is {"" if y in scores else "not "}in the array.')
    
count1(scores)
```

Trying this out:

```
What score are you searching for in the scores array?  3
3 is in the array.

What score are you searching for in the scores array?  12
12 is not in the array.
```

Comment: Assigning the returned value from my function to z worked - thanks a lot